# How to insert data into database (SQL Server) if in model I have "Navigation properties"?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I have such model in asp.net mvc2:

[image]

for example: how I do insert data in table `RouteDetails` ? in db there is field called `RouteId` (wich has relationship with table `Route`)

In the controller I write this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSt(RouteDetail rd)
{
   try
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         db.AddToRouteDetail(rd);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      ModelState.AddModelError("Error!", e);
   }
   return View(rd);
}
```

and view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddSt","Route")) {%>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary(false) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Route.RouteId) %>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Station)%>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StationId) %>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    <% } %>
```

but this doesn't work (if I don't have relationship, it's all ok, but in my situation all is bad).

Why can't I easy write model => model.RouteId ?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks your problem is here

```
 <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Route.RouteId) %>
```

This would imply that you are trying to create a new route object, which I don't believe you are trying to do.  It looks like you want to add a Route Detail to an existing route.

Try pulling the Route out of your database, the adding the Route Detail to the RouteDetails collection, then save the Route object.

Comment: mmm, more details please, i don't understand what you say